# Rational mapping from affine space to projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This problem is highly related to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400613/rational-homotopy-type-of-rational-mapping-spaces) one. Over there I learnt about the Segal's problem regarding the rational mapping spaces. There seems to be a generalization of the result of the Segal for continuous rational mapping spaces from $\mathbb{CP}^n$ to $\mathbb{CP}^m$ due to [Mostovoy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0307103.pdf). The continuous rational mapping seems to be something different than just the rational mapping. It means a regular map that can be extended to a continuous map (from a Zariski dense open). I was wondering whether it is possible to get an understanding of the colimit of homology/homotopy groups of regular mapping space from $U\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ Zariski open to $\mathbb{CP}^m$, where colimit is taken over all such $U$'s. You can assume the degree can be arbitrarily large. (I am not quite sure whether this follows from the Mostovoy's work or not.).

Edit: I am adding another question that might be trivial but I cannot figure it out. Is it possible to extend a regular map $U\subseteq \mathbb{CP}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^m$ to a continuous map $\mathbb{CP}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^m$. (Such a extension does not exist if we replace continuous by regular.)

Comment: Regarding the added question: The Cremona map $(x:y:z) \dashrightarrow (x^{-1}:y^{-1}:z^{-1})$ from $\mathbb{P}^2$ to $\mathbb{P}^2$ is defined on the open set $U$ where $xyz \neq 0$, but it doesn't extend continuously to a map $\mathbb{CP}^2 \to \mathbb{CP}^2$. Note that the two curves $(t:2t:1)$ and $(2t:t:1)$ both limit to the same point $(0:0:1)$ as $t \to 0$, but their Cremona images limit to the distinct points $(1:1/2:0)$ and $(1/2:1:0)$.

Comment: Regarding the second question there is an even simpler example: take the projection $\pi_p:\mathbb{P}^n\dashrightarrow\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$, from a point $p\in\mathbb{P}^n$, with $n\geq 2$.